# Printing right triangle but with powered number

Tags: c#

i have task to print Right Triangle with given example:

```
1
2 4
3 6 9
4 8 12 16
```

i did with this code :

```
public static void Main()
    {
        int val = 5;  
        int i, j, k ;  
        int total = 0;
         for (i = 1; i <= val; i++)  
         {  
            for (j = 1; j <= val-i; j++)  
            {  
               // Console.Write("");  
            }  
            for (k = 1; k <= i; k++)  
            {  total++;
               Console.Write("{0}", Math.Pow(total, 2) );  
            }  
            Console.WriteLine("");  
         }
```

but the result is like this :

```
1
4 9
16 25 36
49 64 81 100
```

how i can do this? thanks in advance

Comment: The best way to find out why your algorithm is not working is to debug it. Try!

Comment: @MaciejLos i know the logic that i made was wrong, but i still don't know how to fix that

Comment: Take a page of paper and a pencil, and write an algorithm in pseudo-code. Then re-write it in c# ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do agree with Maciej that you should think of the algorithm yourself but I think it might still be useful if you have a solution to compare to. I also mostly did it for my own practice since I have problem with things like that as well.
This is just my solution.

```
public static void Main()
    {
        int val = 5;  
        int i, j;  
        int total = 1;
         for (i = 1; i <= val; i++)  
         {  
            total=i;
            for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)  
            {  
               Console.Write("{0}", total );  
               total += i;
            }  
            Console.WriteLine("");  
         }
```

Comment: I'd replace this: `total = total + i` with this: `total += i` ;)

Comment: Done, is there any significant different besides looks writing it like that? @MaciejLos

Comment: @bluejambo thanks for helping me. for `total +=1`  i think there is no big different with that, i think @MaciejLos just trying to simplified the code.

Comment: Well... This form is shorter than yours. On the other hand, i'd suggest to read this: [+ and += operators (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/addition-operator)

Answer (score 1):

This is how your code should look: I made the same pattern in c language please refer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main ()
{
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  int value = 5;

  for (i = 1; i < value; i++)
    {
        for(j = 1; j < i+1; j++){
            printf ("%d ", i*j);
        }
        
        printf ("\n" );
            
        
            
    }
}
```